# Returning from ruby blocks outside of their original scope

Tags: ruby

I wanted to make something that looks like this:

```
def make_wrapped_block(&block)
  puts "take_block:before"
  func = lambda do
    puts "Before calling make_wrapped_block's passed block"
    block.call
    puts "After calling make_wrapped_block's passed block"
  end
  puts "take block:after"
  func
end

def make_block
  make_wrapped_block do
    puts "Before return"
    return :pi
    puts "After return"
  end
end

make_block.call
```

..where there would be many `make_block` methods which generate closures with similar initialization and cleanup provided by `make_wrapped_block`.

Because the block passed to `make_wrapped_block` in `make_block` returns, this causes a LocalJumpError:

```
[ cpm juno ~/tmp/local-jump ] ruby bad.rb
take_block:before
take block:after
Before calling make_wrapped_block's passed block
Before return
bad.rb:15:in `make_block': unexpected return (LocalJumpError)
        from bad.rb:5:in `call'
        from bad.rb:5:in `make_wrapped_block'
        from bad.rb:20:in `call'
        from bad.rb:20
```

Now, I can get this idea to work with a slightly different syntax:

```
def make_wrapped_block(block)
  puts "take_block:before"
  func = lambda do
    puts "Before calling make_wrapped_block's passed block"
    block.call
    puts "After calling make_wrapped_block's passed block"
  end
  puts "take block:after"
  func
end

def make_block
  make_wrapped_block(lambda {
    puts "Before return"
    return :pi
    puts "After return"
  })
end

make_block.call
```

This works because when you return from an anonymous function created with `lambda`, it exits the anonymous function, while with `Proc.new` and anonymous blocks it tries to return from the scope it was defined in. You can't pass them around and return safely.

**Is there a safe way to return from passed blocks outside of the scope they were created?** 
The second way works well enough, but the syntax is a bit uglier than the first version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could catch a `LocalJumpError`:

```
def make_wrapped_block(&block)
  puts "take_block:before"
  func = lambda do
    puts "Before calling make_wrapped_block's passed block"
    begin
      block.call
    rescue LocalJumpError
      # allow return / break
    end
    puts "After calling make_wrapped_block's passed block"
  end
  puts "take block:after"
  func
end

#...

make_block.call
```

But this is a little ugly.

If you don't mind making the return a little awkward, you could use `throw` instead:

```
def make_wrapped_block(&block)
  puts "take_block:before"
  func = lambda do
    puts "Before calling make_wrapped_block's passed block"
    catch (:return) { block.call }
    puts "After calling make_wrapped_block's passed block"
  end
  puts "take block:after"
  func
end

def make_block
  make_wrapped_block do
    puts "Before throw"
    throw :return
    puts "After throw"
  end
end
```

But if this might be a little weird for whoever's writing your `make_block`
methods, unless it's you.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby methods/blocks/closures/lambdas are very inconsistent and a pain in the butt. Here's a comprehensive guide to the [idiosyncrasies](http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby.rb).

What it comes down to in your example is `return`. A `do...end` closure isn't a real closure (for performance reasons). `return`, therefore, does not return out of the `do...end`, but the surrounding method. In a `lambda`, however, `return` exits out of the `lambda` and not the enclosing method, which is the expected behavior.